# modeline does not work in vim

Tags: vim, modeline

I have a file called `.aliases` for bash and zsh, I put this line

```
# vim: set filetype=bash:
```

but if I make

```
: echo &ft
```

I get `conf`

Comment: I've tried everything here and nothing has worked. I've been using vim for 18 years. This is the first time I've failed to get modeline to work.

Comment: Figured it out. Answer below. http://superuser.com/a/1174296/3376

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That should work. I tried that line myself and it worked. I could be that your 'modeline' option got set to 'nomodeline'. Try executing this and see what you get.

```
:verbose set modeline?
```

That will tell you the value of the 'modeline' option and if not the default, where it was last set.

Some Linux distributions set 'nomodeline' in /etc/vimrc or /usr/share/vim/vimrc as a security measure, even though the security problems with 'modeline' have long been fixed.

Comment: modeline
        Last set from ~/.vimrc

Comment: for security, I change the modeline to add this to my ~/.vimrc au BufNewFile,BufRead .*aliases set filetype=sh

Comment: Not all of them have been long fixed. https://github.com/numirias/security/blob/master/doc/2019-06-04_ace-vim-neovim.md

Comment: @duckbrain It is fundamentally impossible to guarantee that all security issues have ever been fixed so long as it is ever possible to include embedded instructions to be executed by the code looking at the data in the very data itself. This is why the documentation for Keith Bostic's *nvi* has always said of `modelines` that the option is UNimplemented and that it never will be. This is just like all the security bugs stemming from file-embedded commands or macro instructions to run in PDF, Word, Excel, &c&c&c.

Answer (score 25):

I describe a [full debug checklist in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41994024/117471).

I was REALLY stumped on this one because [the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) is *not entirely* true.

It turns out that in version 8 (and maybe earlier) you cannot use the word `set` in your modeline. The documentation describes "the second form" as being `/* vim: set ai tw=75: */` but this does not work. You have to use "the first form" `// vim: ai tw=75`

Note: You can use either of those kinds of comment indicators. Or none at all.

Comment: This is not necessarily true for all vim installs. The form with `set` works fine for me on vim 8.0 (although not on 7.4). Also worth noting that with the second form `// vim: ai tw=75`, there cannot be any other characters at the end of the line, or vim will complain and ignore the modeline.

Comment: This should be definitely reported as a bug (or as outdated documentations). I reproduced on `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Inklusive der Korrekturen: 1-1689
Extra-Patches: 8.0.0056
Verändert von pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Übersetzt von pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Riesige Version mit GTK2-GNOME GUI.
` (The last lines mean *modified by ...*, *compiled by ...*, *huge version ...*).

Comment: I tried to address it on the mailing list. They disagreed.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky do you have link to the mail thread? Would like to read their reasoning.

Comment: Here is a link to the thread. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/aFh3X0etB7c/zl0Vi-MuFQAJ I didn't really take the time to understand their reasoning.

Comment: Not working for me with set, just without it. nocompatible doesn't matter. Ubuntu 22.04 Vim 8.2. modeline is set in my .vimrc.  By default nomodline was set in /usr/share/vim/vim82/debian.vim

Answer (score 18):

`set modelines=1` (or any non-0 value) in my ~/.vimrc got it working for me.

Comment: This has no effect if `modeline` is not also set (which it is by default in Vim unless you're root)

Comment: Gentoo has a system-wide `set nomodeline` in `/etc/vimrc` due to all the vulnerabilities with modelines handling in vim.

Comment: In my case, I also had to set `modelines` to a non-zero value. The help says the default is `5`, so that's what I set it to and that did the trick for me. The states that, ```If 'modeline' is on 'modelines' gives the number of lines that is
        checked for set commands.  If 'modeline' is off or 'modelines' is zero
        no lines are checked.```

Answer (score 11):

in ~/.vimrc you need to set following:

```
set nocompatible 
filetype plugin on
set modeline
```

Comment: Those lines work in Debian 9. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Adding just the following to my `~/.vimrc` worked for me on my Funtoo Linux box:

```
set modeline
```

Comment: Does not work in mac !

Answer (score 4):

Since this seems to come up in searches:

I had the same problem:

```
# vim: set filetype=sh:
```

didn't work, resulting in ft=conf as well.
without the modeline in my ~/.bash_alias, ft is empty, so something changes.

while

```
# vim: filetype=sh:
```

worked. the last ":" presence seems to be irrelevant.

I'm on OSX with a Vim8 brewed version, for the records.

it's weird because from the modeline help both

```
[text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]{options}
```

and

```
[text]{white}{vi:|vim:|Vim:|ex:}[white]se[t] {options}:[text]
```

seem to be supported.

The output of

```
verbose set ft?
```

with "vim:filetype=sh" is

```
filetype=sh
      Last set from modeline
```

without modeline:

```
filetype=
```

with "vim:set filetype=sh"

```
filetype=conf
     Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1350/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
```

There might be a side effect somewhere in my conf, but the non compatible modeline syntax is the only one that works as expected for me.

Answer (score 3):

`/usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim` from `vim-common` on **Debian-based** distros disables `modeline` by default.

```
" modelines have historically been a source of security/resource
" vulnerabilities -- disable by default, even when 'nocompatible' is set
set nomodeline
```

You have to enable `modeline` explicitly in your `.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc` file.

```
set modeline
```

Comment: Thanks, and it must be after `set nocompatible` if you use that. On Ubuntu 18.04 and vim version 8.0.1453

Comment: Should that be `~/.vim/.vimrc`? Saving as `~/.vim/vimrc` didn't work for me.

Comment: @user727089 `~/.vimrc` prioritize `~/vim/vimrc`. The latter won't be used if the former is found first.

Comment: No, my question was specifically about the dot (`.`) in the file name. `~/.vim/.vimrc` works, `~/.vim/vimrc` does not.

Comment: @user727089 No `.` is needed, at lease in vim 8. Referred from the help within vim 8 `:help vimrc`. Places for your personal initializations: Unix `$HOME/.vimrc` or `$HOME/.vim/vimrc`.

Comment: @Simba, you're right! I checked again and it works as stated by you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure it works, set both options in your `.vimrc` file (and towards to bottom in case you have a more complicated `.vimrc`):

```
set modeline
set modelines=10
```

The 2nd option will control how many lines to check when searching for potential modeline lines. In case you need to use more than 10 such modeline lines, increase the value (`10` in the example above)

And read also the NOTE in the documentation: `:help modelines`:

> NOTE: 'modeline' is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.

Now depending how complicated `.vimrc` files one might have, changing the value of the `compatible` option (either directly or indirectly by certain plugins, could also influence the modeline behaviour.

But your file should listen now to such comment lines (here an example from my `~/.zshrc`):

```
# vim: tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, even macOS, even as recent as Big Sur, still sets `modelines=0` in the system-wide `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`. So you need to `set modelines=1` in your `~/.vimrc` to override this.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably that's due to modeline being disabled.

I work around that by:

1. keeping it disabled generally to avoid any security issues.
2. Installing [securemodelines](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1876) plugin.
3. Whitelisting only the modelines I use.

In this case, the default whitelisted commands include `filetype`.